# definne object within table cell html5

Tags: css, html, object

What I am trying to achieve is to create an object or something what would help me select the data from different cells. In this example(see the picture bellow) I am trying to put some hidden object on the position where is red dot. This button would then activate four nearest cells. I don't need a script for activation, I just don't have idea what would be the smartest move to position this object within html. Can you please advice me how to do that? Thank you.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Example picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioning the object is possible. Not sure about the click event tho.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  position: relative;
}
td .click {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td><a class="click"></a>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```